# QGIS- python - output name of overlay

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I am writing a pygis plugin in which I need to do an overlay.

The code of the function doing the overlay look like

```
measure=self.dlg.fcbMeasure.layer()
area=self.dlg.fcbArea.layer()
params={'INPUT':measure,
        'OVERLAY':area,
        'OUTPUT':"memory:land_water",
        'INTERSECTION':"memory:land_water"}
processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:intersection", params)
```

I thought either OUTPUT or INTERSECTION should name the output layer, but the layer that is created is just called Intersection - how can I run the intersection and end up with a memory layer named "land_water"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking a bit more around, I found that processing returns a directory with (at least) a key 'OUTPUT'. The value corresponding to this key is a unique layer id.

So I can do

```
output=processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:intersection",params)
newlayer=QgsProject.instance().mapLayer(output['OUTPUT'])
newlayer.setName('land_water')
```

Then I know I have the layer I just created, which is something that is not guaranteed if I start using mapLayersByName() as there may be more map layers with the same name in the project.

Comment: In this way, you probably add the output layer to layer list twice.

Comment: Nope, it works as expected. I am just fetching a pointer to the layer.

Comment: I didn't realize that you used `mapLayer`. I thought it was `addMapLayer`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps someone will know a better way, but the only way I know is via the following workaround:

```
measure=self.dlg.fcbMeasure.layer()
area=self.dlg.fcbArea.layer()
params = {'INPUT': measure,
          'OVERLAY': area,
          'OUTPUT': 'memory'}
processing.runAndLoadResults('qgis:intersection', params)
result = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName('Intersection')[0]
result.setName('land_water')
```

E.g. create a reference to the newly created layer and simply change it's name using the `setName()` method.

**Edit:** The following also works *providing* you have the option in processing settings to 'Use filename as layer name' checked (see image below).

```
measure=self.dlg.fcbMeasure.layer()
area=self.dlg.fcbArea.layer()
params = {'INPUT': measure,
          'OVERLAY': area,
          'OUTPUT': 'land_water'}
processing.runAndLoadResults('qgis:intersection', params)
```

[image]